# using HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django

In one of my view function, under certain condition I want to redirect to another URL.
So I am doing

`return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(next_view, kwargs={'name': name1}))`

Now I have another view function like

`def next_view(request, name):`

I also put following line in relevant urls.py file

```
from wherever import next_view

urlpatterns = patterns("",
                        url(r"^next_view/(?P<name>w+)/", next_view, name="next_view"),
                       )
```

This does not work, I get

```
Reverse for 'next_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'name': u'test'}' not found.
```

Comment: If you're using sub `urls.py` file, does the application is installed? Have you tried with `reverse('next_view', ...)` (in quotes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the regex isn't matching properly.  How about:

```
r"^next_view/(?P<name>\w+)/"
```

Note the backslash before the 'w'.

Comment: Thank you very much. I somehow missed that backslash, and suffered for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

For `urls.py` you want to add the backslash before the `w+` and also add a `$` sign at then end of the URL so that any other URL's joined onto this will be accepted:

```
urlpatterns = patterns("",
  url(r"^next_view/(?P<name>\w+)/$", next_view, name="next_view"),
  )
```

For `views.py` you want to add parenthesis around your view name:

```
def example_view(self):
  # view code 
  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('next_view', kwargs={'name': name1}))
```